# How do I access a functions' property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I am new to Javascript and I wanted to know how I should append the variable red_btn to my document. The code currently does not work. I am not used to using functions so is my code correct. I wanted to make a few more buttons in Buttons() function. Please help me out.

```
function CreateCircle(r, color){
    let canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(240, 200, r, 0 , 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}

function Buttons(){
    const red_btn = document.createElement("button");
    red_btn.innerHTML = "Button";
    red_btn.name = "red_btn";
    red_btn.type = "button";
    red_btn.innerText = "Red";
}

document.body.appendChild(Buttons.red_btn);
```

Comment: The OP's `Buttons` function needs to return the created button element, thus `red_btn` is the function's return value and not the `Buttons` function's property. `function createButton() { const elm = document.createElement("button"); /* ... ... */ return elm;}` ... and then as often as the OP needs it ... `document.body.appendChild(createButton());`

Comment: Check my adjusted answer.

Comment: In addition, trying to create additional markup of not existing html elements like `Button` within the just created button element via ... `red_btn.innerHTML = "Button";` ... does not make any sense. The OP could have read some documentation on the matter ( [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) / [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) ) before showing up at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just the following:

```
function Buttons(){
    const red_btn = document.createElement("button");
    red_btn.innerHTML = "Button";
    red_btn.name = "red_btn";
    red_btn.type = "button";
    red_btn.innerText = "Red";

    return red_btn;
}
    
document.body.appendChild(Buttons());
```

Comment: A multiple times edited, hastily given, quick shot answer like the above, yet already rewarded with 2 upvotes, should at least undergo a final editing where the provided solution gets explained. In addition it should notify about and fix the OP's most obvious mistake/s which is/are still carried with the answer's example code.

Comment: @Obsidianlab so if I add more buttons due to the `document.body.appendChild(Buttons());` the buttons are overlapping

Comment: @zapernewlson ... If the buttons are overlapping, it is due to whatever css rules are applied to a plain 'button' selector within the OP's environment (or the OP has additionally applied class name/s and/or styling to such a button). If one takes the above code as is, and appends more buttons, no overlapping will happen.

Comment: @zapernewlson as peter stated that is most likely CSS related and you will have to post your new question in another SO question. Since this answer helped you make sure to mark it as accepted answer.